# How to debug runtime crash in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, crash, crashlytics

I am using Crashlytics to capture crashes in my app once it has been distributed.

One of the issues I am trying to debug involves a tableview datasource which is causing an occasional crash because it is returning nil in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

[image]

Debugging this is proving to be quite difficult, though, because the crash report gives me no clues (that I can see!) as to which data source class is the problem! The entire stack trace seems to contain references to UIKit / CoreFoundation, and at no point is any of my own code referenced.

Since this is a fairly large app (there are over 40 classes which implement cellForRowAtIndexPath throughout the application) - is there anything I can do, other than manually pick through every class, to try and find the cause of this issue? The issue has only been seen a handful of times and as yet I am unaware of the steps to reproduce.

Comment: Well, you can add your own asserts to your data sources to catch a null cell being returned.

Comment: And, of course, it should not take that long to make a quick scan through 40 data source classes and generate a list of the suspect ones (because their data flow is not straight-forward and relatively idjit-proof).

Comment: Provide your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and we can take a look. In my experience, the most likely problem is that your data source is changing while your view is being updated. `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` get called shortly before the corresponding cells get called in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. This is not 100% synchronous however, and it is possible that the cell/section count gets returned and then your array (or whatever your data source is) changes, causing the requested data to no longer exist by the time it is requested.

Comment: @Dima - The problem is, he has about 40 of them.

Comment: @HotLicks I see. One thing that improved the value of Crashlytics logs for me immensely is that I began adding a `CLS_LOG()` into every `viewWillAppear:` (and a few other places) in my app. Even just doing that allows you to track a user's movement through your app (provided you do indeed use multiple view controllers). Then, finding the correct tableview would be as simple as checking the last logged line for that crash.